# Installing php-cgi under Ubuntu for Cherokee web server

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, webserver

I have set up Cherokee web server on my server, and want to enable PHP and MySQL support for applications like Wordpress and phpBB.

I have tried running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server
```

And they both install, but when I try to link Chrokee with PHP in the admin interface it says it needs `php-cgi`? I also tried doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-cgi
```

But I got this error:

```
E: Couldn't find package php-cgi
```

I'm fairly new to setting up web servers and such so if someone could give me an example of how to set this up properly, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I have to ask....why Cherokee? If you are new to Web servers, it's probably going to be a lot quicker for you to set up Apache with mod php.  I work in Web operations & had to google cherokee to even find out what it was.

Answer (score 1):

The exact package is php5-cgi. From ubuntu 8.04 the simplest way to install it is:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

I use debian rather than ubuntu, but while the exact package names vary the packaging software doesn't so this should work:

`apt-cache search php5 cgi`

That should return a list of all packages that contain the "php5" and "cgi" keywords in their description; sifting through them to find the one you need shouldn't be too hard.